# What techniques exist for working with "iterated" functions such as f(f(x))?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

I keep encountering questions that sound like obscure puzzles, involving expressions such as $f(f(x))$.  I don't know of any techniques for working with such things, or getting from knowledge of $f(f(x))$ to knowledge of $f(x)$, other than guesswork.  Is there a subject that covers this topic?  A reference text?  Or is it simply a random handful of off-the-wall questions with no general theory?

Comment: You could also find a variety of problems posted previously on the site.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti Thank you for the references!  That's exactly what I was looking for.